# ComScore Analytics on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, analytics, comscore

Had anybody done analytics with ComScore  on iPhone? I am not able to understand how to start it. Can anyone help me in this please? - objective-c.

Comment: Do you happen to have SDK for ComScore? If yes share the SDK or where to get it from.

Comment: yes , i have SDK .. i got it from my client  but don't know how to make calls for tagging events or screens.

Comment: I have used another Analytics in one of iPhone Application I wrote for my client. Send me an email at nikita.stackoverflow@gmail.com if the SDK can't be shared with everybody here. I can help you out.

Comment: i will attach it here only .. no probs .. :)

Comment: Go to www.comscore.com , resister the new user. 
Go to Direct -> mobile app -> get tag
here you will get  C2 and publisher secret with left side the sdk and "how to do" instructions. That instructions i already followed..done with it also but what I need is "how to tag events and screen?"..

Comment: Update to Neelam's link, start at https://direct.comscore.com instead of www.comscore.com, as their main site is mainly for Enterprise level clients, and finding the link to direct can be difficult to find.

Comment: Thanks @JasonK. for answering, 2 years back i was in some project , was need of ComScore But then afterwards we did analytics using Google Analytics.

Answer (score 3):

One can find answer here in this [here](http://www.cmf-fmc.ca/documents/files/about/ind-outreach/2012-13/appendix-c2-additional-tagging-spec.pdf) pdf i used it for android.

Comment: sorry but the page link is now moved. I need to add it in Android, and I am also not able to know how to start it. can you please help me fot the same.

Comment: @PDWaghela, you can either search this pdf on their website 'appendix-c2-additional-tagging-spec.pdf' or you can directly go to link http://www.cmf-fmc.ca/documents/files/about/ind-outreach/2012-13/sept-27/appendix-c2-additional-tagging-spec.pdf

Comment: @RaviK.Sharma: Can u suggest some links to integrate with swift project with new sdk version?

Answer (score 1):

The init method for ComScore is:

```
    [CSComScore setAppContext];
```

But I believe you can also use:

```
    [CSComScore start];
    // Or...
    [CSComScore startWithLabels:@{@"label1":@"value1"}];
```

And to track view changes/appearances:

```
    [CSComScore view];
    // Or..
    [CSComScore viewWithLabels:@{@"testLabelA2":@"testValueA2", @"testLabelB2":@"testValueB2"}];
```

Be sure to look at the ComScore.h header file for the full list of methods used by their library.

Comment: Thanks for the help .. I will try above API in future.

Comment: I have tried ComScore SDK in iOS app but how to call media events like play, pause, resume using ComScore SDK.

Comment: @vipulk617: I believe you only need to notify the SDK when a media event starts and stops with the 'onUxActive' and 'onUxInactive' commands. See page 11 of Comscore's getting started guide:

http://www.cmf-fmc.ca/documents/files/programs/dm-reporting/comscore/application-tag-ios-digital-analytix-us.pdf

Comment: I have used this methods on start playing video and end video . But not get any play , pause and resume events .

Comment: Can someone help me to do this in swift, the SDK is now updated : https://cocoapods.org/pods/ComScore